# How can I import iso-latin1 encoded text into DOORS

Tags: excel, character-encoding, ibm-doors

I have reworked some testcases in Excel and exported them as tab stop separated file. Unfortunately, there are some German letters in this export namely Ä,ä,ö,Ö,ü,Ü,ß as being specified in iso-8859-1.

When I now import my tabstop separated file in DOORS I obtain only gibberish, as the encoding is not taken over correctly. I tried to save my import file in UTF-8 and iso-8859-1 alike.

I import with the option "Import Worksheet", is this maybe the reason, as there are also other means of importing.

Is there any way I can proceed with my bad import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- check that the file is really iso-8859-1 or UTF-8 encoded, e.g. by looking at it with a hex viewer (iso-8859-1 lower case ü is hex FC (dec 252). utf-8 lower case ü is hex c3 bc) or with an editor that tells you the current encoding.
- in module explorer -> "File" -> "import" -> "Spreadsheet…", first enter the full path to the input file, then press "Advanced". Here you can set the encoding of the file you want to import (28591 is ISO-8859-1, 28603 is ISO-8859-13 (which is used most of the time, since it contains the € symbol,  65001 is UTF-8) and you get a preview.

Comment: Many thanks. So easy to to do, but didn't found the button.